# WordPress snippet - post password protection check

Tags: wordpress, code-snippets

Hello i want to run a content modification snippet but only on password protected posts.

```
function func($content) {

   if( $post->password_protected ){
      $content = [whatever]
   }

   return $content;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'func');
```

how can i do that password_protected check?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out

```
if( !empty($GLOBALS['post']->post_password) ){..}
```